# JavaFX Scene Builder yellow boxes do not disappear

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using the JavaFX Scene Builder (with and without Intellij Idea) in the following version:

```
Product Version
JavaFX Scene Builder 8.3.0

Build Information
Version 8.3.0
Date: 2016-12-16
Java Version: 1.8.0_111-b14, Oracle Corporation
```

The problem is draggin around items in the editor, the editor shows a yellow shadow to show a preview where the item will be. However, these yellow boxes do not disapear. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHbBG.png)
Additionally, sometimes it is not possible to drag new items or select other items, the selection seems to stay somewhere.

Does anybody has a similar problem and preferably a solution?

Thanks

[image: screenshot javafx scene builder]

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I get is closing the sample.fxml or whatever  file you working on it and re open it and by searching they talking about standalone scene builder the embedded one is buggy i think, but I didnt try the stand alone one yet